# How to toggle between vim buffer and command shell screen in vim?

Tags: vim, bashrc

I find it annoying to constantly press `Ctrl-Z` and then `fg` to go between these screens (where command terminal is the command line that you used to invoke `vim` from).  It also generates unwanted `fg` lines on my console.  I'm pretty sure this can be done as I remember doing it when I was in university, but I can't remember how.

## Information on Terminals and its Relation to vim

vt100 terminal and others have a way to save the screen prior to changing it and then it could restore it when it wants to.  `vim` does this and can be seen if you go into `vim` and then shell or `Ctrl-Z` out.  Most of the time it will show you what you had on the screen prior to entering `vim` by saving the screen prior to painting the `vim` screen.  If your terminal doesn't support this functionality, it will just put the command line directly under the `vim` screen, scrolling it up.  This can be seen by exporting to the TERM variable a less functional terminal emulation or clearing it (though by clearing it, it may put `vim` into line mode or may use the most basic of terminal codes depending on its implementation).  To see more on saving/restoring a screen, see [Terminal codes (ANSI/VT100) introduction](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes), under the heading *Save/restore screen*.

Comment: Would setting `HISTIGNORE` to `fg:bg` be enough? (It would prevent these two commands from ending in your history, assuming bash.) Or is there something more that you find irritating?

Comment: I don't want it displayed on the screen.  If I switch back and forth, the console screen will start to scroll and the thing that I'm looking at will move off page.

Comment: Some terminal apps have a "second screen" that some programs, for example `less`, use. I have no idea, though, how to flip between them by keyboard command. Since I normally work with the gnome desktop, I use `evim` (because I'm a `vim` newbie but a GUI person since the late 80's), which, as another answer points out, works around the problem.

Comment: Its a workaround, but doesn't answer my question. :/

Comment: Use vim in `screen` or `tmux` and use another window?

Comment: @muru, yeah, thought of that, but seems a bit overkill.

Comment: You could type (or create a macro that does) `:silent !sleep 999999` . This will show your saved screen until you type Control-C, and (because of the :silent command) it won't print any `Press ENTER to continue` messages on the saved screen. A `^C` will be printed, though.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, that's *very* close to what I want!  Now I have to look into scripts to see if I can get the following command to be run (which is bash, or similar) and then refresh the screen upon returning: `:silent !read -sN 1`

Comment: Its amazing how ppl downvote without thinking, and how some downvote while thinking that the person writing the question wasn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I've figured out how I can do this with Gary Johnson's help on the [Google Groups vim_use](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/5ZgILsZkIuc) group.  He helped by stating how to run the `tput` commands from vim.  Here is my final solution:

1. Have the following function script in vim memory:

   ```
   function! ShowTerm()
       call system(">/dev/tty tput rmcup")
       call input("")
       call system(">/dev/tty tput smcup")
       redraw!
   endfunction
   ```
2. Map the script to some command key sequence like this:

   ```
   map [= :call ShowTerm()<CR>
   ```

I used the sequence `[=`, but you can use whatever you want.

Now type the *key sequence* and you get the other screen.  Press *Enter* and you're back to the vim screen.  The Enter doesn't add a line feed to the terminal screen either, so no marching lines.

Nice! :)  Note that this probably isn't the way it was done 15-20 years ago, but it works.

## EDIT

In order not to be dependent on `tput` being available, I've found that the following that @MarkPlotnick inferred works just as well.  Just replace the function `ShowTerm()` above with:

```
function! ShowTerm()
    silent !read -sN 1
    redraw!
endfunction
```

This depends on `bash` being used as the shell (or others that have a similar read call).

## 2nd Edit

Further, you can have this automated by putting a `.vim` file into your ~/.vim/plugins folder that contains the following:

```
" Function that allows viewing command line display last time it was seen.
" Note: Will only work on terminals that allow saving/restoring the display.
function! ShowTerm()
    " This will invoke the command shell and call the read function.
    " Will exit when a key is pressed.  This is specific to bash and
    " and may have to be changed if using a different shell.
    silent !read -sN 1
    redraw!
endfunction

" Maps [= sequence to view command line display last time it was seen.
map [= :call ShowTerm()<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting `gvim` opens a new window, so the terminal window stays available for commands. For intermediate "shell escapes" I do `:sh` to get access to a shell session, and type `<Ctrl>-D` to exit it; no `fg` is needed, but a prompt is added in this case to the console shell. And with no `X` running I start two consoles, one where vim is running, and the other where the shell is running, and I switch consoles by (in my case) e.g. `<Ctrl>-<Alt>-<F1>`. (Depending on the actual needs, one of those options should fit; I hope.)

Comment: I don't use a graphical vim app.  Just a terminal version.  I've used this in uni 15-20 years ago, and though that was a long time ago, I don't think I'm going senile. ;)

Comment: The graphical vim is actually just a normal vim (with only a few more convenient features). Myself being a IT-dinosaur, a vi enthusiast, and a terminal junkie, I think it's worth (if possible) to use gvim. You can, of course, also just start an ordinary vim in another window if you like.

Comment: Yeah, I'd rather not use a 2nd terminal for reasons I don't care to explain.  I guess I could go back to screen, but that seems overkill.

Comment: How do you think should `vim` accomplish the task of switching to the parent shell process and resuming? You need some controlling process to do so. Otherwise the options are as shown by exemple; controlling process is the window session or console manager, or the application spawns a new shell, or the shell's job-control interrupts the running editor and you resume.

Comment: IIRC, it switches by using terminal codes to switch between saved pages.  See [Terminal codes (ANSI/VT100) introduction](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes) under **Save/restore screen**.  Most terminals have this functionality, and I think that is how vim does it so that you have access to the console view when you shell to it.  I just want it to flip between these without having to cause the console screen to scroll.

Comment: If it is (as you assume) a `vim` feature you'll certainly find it in the `vim` documentation.

Comment: there are a lot of `vim` features that are difficult to find in the docs, and am why I'm asking here.

Comment: Downvote of your question because "this question does not show any research effort".

Comment: you are of course welcome to do that if you think that is the case.  You'd be wrong, but it is your right.

Comment: Reading the docs of a tool and searching with keywords for a specific feature is simple, and I'd expect that. You're of course free to use the convenient way and just ask. But then insisting on something being a feature of the tool and not supporting that opinion is cheap. - Back on topic; I'm not sure the ANSI controls that you mentioned would do the job during an edit session; it seems to me the description just explains what the tools do to restore the screen at termination to the state from where they started, so that they can muddle with the screen as they like.

Comment: So you don't think I've tried that?  You'd be wrong. Those 'ANSI controls' are terminal codes which are sent through the text stream and interpreted by the terminal.  It is how `vim` can be displayed on a terminal cleanly as it has to move the cursor around, change colours of text and do many other things that cannot be done on a simple line terminal.  The `tput` command is merely a easy API for a shell programme to use them, but is actually done by a lower level API which is used directly by `vim` and are analogous to GUI APIs except much less powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Does the Vim command `:shell` work as you want? `:shell<return>` causes Vim to run your $SHELL.  When you exit the shell, you're back in Vim, right where you left off.

Comment: no, as I said, I want to toggle between the two screens without unwanted lines being generated in the console.

Comment: @Adrian Most shells don't have separate "screens" unless you use something like `tmux` or a terminal emulator with tab support. Maybe your question is really "how can I run a command without its name being echoed"?

Comment: @Adrian - I don't understand what you mean by "Console" in that case. You'll have to use more standard terminology, as what you asked just plain doesn't make sense. "Console" has a somewhat specific meaning in the context of X11 interfaces, but as far as I know, "Console" doesn't mean anything specific with respect to vim.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the terminal shell prompt.  What do you mean by "running a command without its name being echoed?"

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> can be used to switch between split panes in vim also works with terminal split.